# Convert mixed input to hex

Tags: python, regex, hex

So my input is a mix of hex and ascii data. e.g. `input=|3E 00|redcar|0D|.` Here the data inside the pipes(| |) is hex. I want to convert everything not in pipes to hex such that I get a fully hex output.

If input is `|3E 00|redcar|0D|` , I want `output= 3E007265646361720D`. This is what I did so far:

```
import re

inputt = |3E 00|redcar|0D|
hexx = re.findall('\|(.*?)\|', inputt)
output= ' '.join(hexx).replace(" ", "")
print output #3E000D
```

How do I access the part not in pipes, convert it to hex (easy part), and put everything back in correct order? Thanks

**Edit:**
I should add that it is not a must that hex comes before and after ascii in input. It can also be `input=redcar|0D|` or `input=|3E 00|redcar`. So the solution needs to be general.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub` with a callable as a replacement:

```
import re
s = '|3E|redcar|0D|'
print(re.sub(r'(\|[^|]*?\|)|([^|]*)', lambda t: t.group(1) or ''.join(format(ord(c), 'x') for c in t.group(2)), s))
```

This outputs:

```
|3E|726564636172|0D|
```

Comment: Hi. This gives me a TypeError. Is there a syntax issue?

Comment: If you're using Python version prior to 3.6, you have to use `t.group(1)` instead of `t[1]`. I've updated my answer to be compatible with earlier versions then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use capture groups. [See here](https://regex101.com/r/3jLf4S/1).

I'm not sure how consistent your piping is, so you might need to edit this a bit, but here's the pattern. `\|(.+)\|(.*)\|(.+)\|`

group 1 is the prefix, group 2 is the part you need to convert to hex, and group 3 is the post-fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `(\|[^\|]+\||^)(\w+?)(\|[^\|]+\||$)`.

Every match will have three capturing groups:

- first, `(\|[^\|]+\||^)` will be hex at the beginning or zer-width match if there isn't any,
- second will be ASCII string: `(\w+?)`, you could even use `.` instead of `\w`,
- third, `(\|[^\|]+\||$)`, will be hex at the end, if there's any.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ltu0Wz/1)

Answer (score 0):

It easy to solve without regex:

```
s='|3E 00|redcar|0D|'
rslt=[]
pipe=0
for ch in s:
    if ch=='|':
        pipe+=1
        continue
    if pipe%2:
        if ch==" ":
            continue
        rslt.append(ch)
    else:
        rslt.append(f"{ord(ch):02X}")

print("".join(rslt))
'3E007265646361720D'
```